# Customizing Dates with CAST function using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How do I get the CAST function to convert...

```
2011-10-30 09:32:40.000
```

into

```
10-30
```

The Statement below includes the year (which I don't want)...

```
CAST(DateAdded AS date) AS CastToDate
```

There are multiple rows with different dates that will need to be converted to only show the month and day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to convert your datetime value to text using conversion mask `110`, which uses the format `mm-dd-yy`.  Then, just take the left most 5 characters, which include the month and day:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, date_col, 110), 5)
FROM yourTable;

10-30
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on a reasonably modern version you can use the `FORMAT` function.

This is more readable than extracting a substring from the result of an operation with a cryptic numeric code.

```
select format(getdate(),'MM-dd')
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/VOSNW56891)